# Why does python3 --version show an incorrect version after installing it from source inside Docker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I've installed Python 3.9.6 from sources, in the same way I do for a lot of times:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tgz

tar -xvf ...

./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=/usr && make -j && make install
```

Yet when running `python3.9 --version` I get:

```
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 29 2022, 04:38:19)
```

1. I definitely have no other `python3.9` binaries aside from the installed ones:
   `which -a python3.9` shows only `/usr/bin/python3.9`
2. System is Debian 10 Buster for that matter, running inside Docker.

Can anyone help resolve this mystery?

Comment: I'd guess that the binaries are installed in `/usr/local/bin/`, and that directory is not inside `$PATH`. When you run `make install`, what directory is it installing Python to?

Comment: Match isn't available in either 3.9.6 or 3.9.10 - only in 3.10!

Comment: @NickODell that was my first guess as well, however, I see `--prefix=/usr` on the command line for `configure`.

Comment: Did you have your build log ?

Comment: Adiel, what do you get for `--version` if you execute whatever is in the build directory? One possibility is that whatever is picked up by searching PATH is not the same as what's in the build directory. Something to look at, anyway.

Comment: @NickODell you're right about match availability - my bad. so its even weirder!

Comment: @RobertDodier where can i find the executeable in build dir before running make install? i'll check

Comment: I don't know where exactly it would be, but I think it is going to be an executable file which is named `python` or `python3` or `python3.9` or `python3.9.something`. (Some of those might exist as symbolic links ...) Try `cd path/to/build/directory` and then `find . -type f -name python\* -ls` and look for executable files.

Comment: It's `python` directly in the build directory.

Comment: @RobertDodier i found the binary in build source dir, it also shows 3.9.10 as well

Comment: This may be completely off the mark, but [`which` is often the wrong tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I just build the 3.9.6 version on Ubuntu and got the correct version.

Comment: I think i found the root cause. my docker image was built "FROM python:3.9-slim-buster" which by default contains 3.9.10. Still not clear though why after overriding it with python3.9.6 i still get executable of 3.9.10

Comment: Are you sure that the install run without error ? Because `/usr` is not writable by most user.

Comment: no errors, and since the base docker image ends with CMD ["python3"] - this is why i get 3.9.10 all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to docker env which was using "FROM python:3.9-slim-buster".
This docker has 3.9.10 installed, and the entrypoint is actually "CMD ["python3"]".
No real issue here.